Calculation isn't printing to the excel document
I am trying to calculate the absolute change between two different years for a country - the code I have written below is the function I have created in order to do exactly this. However I am having a issue with the computation printing to the excel file I have created.
When running the code only the Country column on the output excel file is filled and not the AC change column and I am unsure of what the issue is on why the result is only printing to one column and not the other.
Here is an example of the dataframe containing the excel file I am trying to analyse.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['Austria', 'Austria'],
                   'REGION_2D': ['AT10', 'AT10'],
                   'Variable': ['ILOSTAT_W', 'ILOSTAT_W'],
                   'variable_type':[1, 1],
                   'value': [1798.52, 1804.577],
                   'YEAR': [2018, 2021]})

Here is the code I have developed for it.
Any help on this would be much appreciated.
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as op


df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\blakecar\PycharmProjects\LFS Data\Mock File LFS.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')

output = pd.DataFrame()

output["Country"] = ""
output["Region"] = ""
output["AC_Change"] = ''

def func1(geog):
    print("------------")
    print(geog)
    print("------------")
    filtered_df = df[df["COUNTRY"].isin([geog])]
    filtered_df = filtered_df[filtered_df["REGION_2D"].isin(["AT10"])]
    filtered_df = filtered_df[filtered_df["Variable"].isin(["ILOSTAT_W"])]

    filtered_2018 = filtered_df[filtered_df["YEAR"].isin(["2018"])]
    total_2018 = filtered_2018['value'].sum()

    filtered_2021 = filtered_df[filtered_df['YEAR'].isin(["2021"])]
    total_2021 = filtered_2021['value'].sum()

    return total_2018 - total_2021

geo = df['COUNTRY'].unique()
for geog in geo:
    funcValue = func1(geog)
    output.loc[len(output)] = {"Country": geog, 'AC_change':funcValue}

output.to_excel('Mock File.xlsx', index=False)


The output I am hoping to get is the result of the calculation I have done in the function in the code
so it would look something like this:



Country
Ac_Change




Austria
2018 - 2021








Your issue seems unrelated to Excel, so I'll just focus on the pandas part.
You should pre-filter the REGION_2D/Variable (for example with query), then run a groupby.sum, finally slice the years of interest, subtract them and reset_index:
total = (df
   .query('(REGION_2D in ["AT10"]) and (Variable in ["ILOSTAT_W"])')
   .groupby(['YEAR', 'Country'])['value'].sum()
)

out = (total.loc[2018] - total.loc[2021]).reset_index(name='AC_change')

Output:
   Country  AC_change
0  Austria     -6.057


Thanks but it still doesn't print the result when I run the code

What do you mean by "doesn't print"? If you want to print it in your terminal/notebook print(out), if you want to export it as excel, output.to_excel('Mock File.xlsx', index=False). If something is "not working", you have to clearly explain how (explain what/where/how you get and what/where/how you would expect instead).
